# let $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there exist n consecutive natural numbers which are all divisible by a k-th power

Tags: number-theory

Let $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there exist $n$ consecutive natural numbers  which are all divisible by a $k$-th power of some integer larger then 1.

I think that i need to use the chinese remainder theorem, but maybe i just don't understand it well enough and that's the reason i can't seem to solve this question. I thought that i'd choose these equalities to let the gcd of two numbers always be 1:

$x \equiv 0 \pmod{2^k}$

$x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3^k}$

$\vdots$

$x+n \equiv 0 \pmod{p_n^k}$

the Chinese Remainder Theorom now states that we got a unique residue class modulo

$P = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} p_i^k$.

but does this mean that $P \mid (x+i)$ for $i \in \{1, \cdots , n\}$? And if this is true why is that?

Kees

Comment: nevermind, i understand it now, there is a solution $x = y (\mod P)$ that fits in all these equations,  so we can find a number x that seems to work so it must exist :).

Comment: LaTeX tips: Use `\pmod{k}` to get "(mod *k*)", `\mid` for the "divides" symbol, and `\vdots` for vertical ellipsis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means that there exists a solution $x$ with $x = y(\mod P)$ for these equations, which answers the question, because this specific x works just fine :)